# Laravel 4 create an user programatically with Zizaco/confide

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a user with the Zizaco/confide library, the user data comes from Facebook and not from a form.

I try this :

```
$user_profile = Facebook::api('/me','GET');

$new_user = new User;

$new_user->username = $user_profile['name'];
$new_user->password = Hash::make('secret');
$new_user->email = $user_profile['email'];
$new_user->confirmation_code = '456456';
$new_user->confirmed = true;

$new_user->save();
```

but it doesn't save the user. Any help ?

Comment: does it silently go over it or or throw any error? any logs in app/storage/logs/laravel.log?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I posted the answer, the problem were the validation rules

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, the confide library sets some default rules to create the user, you need to pass this rules to save a user:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:users',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|between:4,11|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'between:4,11',
);
```

with this example it works:

```
$user = new User();

$user->username = 'asdasd';
$user->email = 'angorusadf@gmail.com';
$user->password = '12312312';
$user->password_confirmation = '12312312';

$user->save();
```

Mabe the method should give you some information when you don't pass the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a pretty late answer, but I'm posting this for future reference because I was myself looking for an answer to the same question, `How to create a user programatically in zizaco/confide?` or more generally, `how to bypass zizaco/confide's requirement for setting a password when saving a user for the first time?`

well, the answer is pretty simple, thanks to the new architecture which Zizaco implemented in the 4.* branch, it's now possible to register a new user validator class see more at [the package's readme](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/tree/master#custom-user-validation) in short all you need in this very case though, is just to extend the current User validator and override `validatePassword()`  to make it accept empty passwords for new users.

**Below is an example implementation:**

In `routes.php`

```
 // we need to register our validator so that it gets used instead of the default one
 // Register custom Validator for ConfideUsers

 App::bind('confide.user_validator', 'MyUserValidator');
```

In  `app/models/MyUserValidator.php` (that's basically a copy of the function in the class, simply just added a check whether this is a old user or not (if the user has an ID then this is an update operation) if this is a new user, the method always returns true!

```
/**
 * Class MyUserValidator
 * Custom Validation for Confide User
 */
class MyUserValidator extends \Zizaco\Confide\UserValidator //implements \Zizaco\Confide\UserValidatorInterface
{

    /**
     * Validates the password and password_confirmation of the given
     * user
     * @param  ConfideUserInterface $user
     * @return boolean  True if password is valid
     */
    public function validatePassword(\Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUserInterface $user)
    {
        $hash = App::make('hash');

        if($user->getOriginal('password') != $user->password && $user->getOriginal('id')) {
            if ($user->password == $user->password_confirmation) {

                // Hashes password and unset password_confirmation field
                $user->password = $hash->make($user->password);

                unset($user->password_confirmation);
                return true;
            } else {
                $this->attachErrorMsg(
                    $user,
                    'validation.confirmed::confide.alerts.wrong_confirmation',
                    'password_confirmation'
                );
                return false;
            }
        }
        unset($user->password_confirmation);
        return true;
    }
}
```